# Get number from string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, selenium-webdriver

I have a string, I have to get digits only from that string.

```
 url = "www.mylocalurl.com/edit/1987"
```

Now from that string, I need to get `1987` only.
I have been trying this approach,

```
id = [int(i) for i in url.split() if i.isdigit()]
```

But I am getting `[]` list only.

Comment: Try: `id = [int(i) for i in url if i.isdigit()]`

Comment: `url.split()` will return the whole url, due to the string not containing any whitespaces. Did you mean to try `url.split("/")`?

Comment: @HampusLarsson I did, but still I am getting [].

Comment: `[int(i) for i in url.split("/") if i.isdigit()]` returns `[1987]` for me though, are you sure that you're not running the old unchanged code?

Comment: @HampusLarsson your last solution is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex and get the digit alone in the list.

```
import re
url = "www.mylocalurl.com/edit/1987"
digit = re.findall(r'\d+', url)
```

output:

`['1987']`

Answer (score 0):

Replace all non-digits with blank (effectively "deleting" them):

```
import re

num = re.sub('\D', '', url)
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/gYPkrX).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting anything because by default the `.split()` method splits a sentence up where there are spaces. Since you are trying to split a hyperlink that has no spaces, it is not splitting anything up. What you can do is called a capture using regex. For example:

```
import re
url = "www.mylocalurl.com/edit/1987"
regex = r'(\d+)'
numbers = re.search(regex, url)
captured = numbers.groups()[0]
```

If you do not what what regular expressions are, the code is basically saying. Using the `regex` string defined as `r'(\d+)'` which basically means capture any digits, `search` through the url. Then in the `captured` we have the first captured group which is `1987`.

If you don't want to use this, then you can use your `.split()` method but this time provide a split using `/` as the separator. For example `url.split('/').